# How to convert the nominal data from csv to arff format?

Tags: weka, openrefine

one of the attribute was 'first year, second year'. when i tried to open into Weka, i got the errors the following error message "unable to determine structure as arff(Reasons:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A nominal attribute (year) cannot have duplicate labels (year)".

i followed all of the steps for the file to be opened in Weka as i did it with the numerical value of the same datasets that was worked. i followed the below steps:

1. @relation (Name)
2. @attribute year {first year, second year}
3. @data
   first year
   second year

Answer (score 0):

Nominal vales that contain spaces must be quoted, as per:

https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_stable/#nominal-attributes

In your case:

`@attribute year {'first year', 'second year'}`

Also, Weka can load CSV files. Either  natively or via the [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package) Weka package.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick reply and very much appreciated. Yes, as you point out Weka can convert the csv file into arff format and i have tried it, it worked. However, in my assignment i was asked to perform this manually using notepad editing. so, i put the quotes in the 'first year' and 'second year' per your suggestion, but it the section @data, how to change or ensure that all data in that column are quoted?

Comment: Find and Replace functionality of the editor.

Comment: i fixed the issue by putting a hyphen between first and year because it was recognized by OpenRefine as two separate words. For e.g; by replacing 'first year' with 'first-year', it worked.